# AIX 7.1, Vim error after Yum upgrade. Cannot allocate color SlateBlue

Tags: vim, yum, aix

On AIX 7.1 after installing yum and then running update, vim threw an error:

```
Error detected while processing 
/opt/freeware/share/vim/vim80/syntax/syncolor.vim:
line   46:
E254: Cannot allocate color SlateBlue
```

Comment: Self-answered Questions are fine, but do please put the answer in the Answer box.

Comment: What update did you run, and what did it do?

Comment: It was an all new yum install. This happened after running "yum update" after the initial install was finished.

Answer (score 2):

```
cp /usr/lpp/X11/lib/X11/rgb.txt /opt/freeware/share/vim/vim80/
```